# Run .bat file from cmd.exe in C# with various arguments

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, cmd, process

I've been trying all day to start process which would run the following code:

`C:\bin\ant.bat -f=C:\build.xml -DinputFile=C:\Desktop\Book1.xml -DstartDate=2018-06-20 -DxslFile=ProcessingDate -DoutputFile=fff`

and it works completely fine in `cmd`.

this is my last code in C# which I really hoped would work, but however it doesn't:

```
public void run() {
        string antFile = @"C:\ant.bat";
        string build = @"C:\build.xml";
        string inputFile = @"C:\Book1.xml";
        string startDate = "2018-05-23";
        string outputFile = "ff";
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c" + @"C:bin\ant.bat -f=C:\build.xml -DinputFile=C:\Desktop\Book1.xml -DstartDate=2018-06-20 -DxslFile=ProcessingDate -DoutputFile=test0.xsl");
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();

        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo2 = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c" + antFile + "-f=" + build + "-DinputFile=" + inputFile + "-DstartDate=" + startDate + "-DxslFile=" + startDate + "-DoutputFile=" + outputFile);
        Process proc2 = new Process();
        proc2.StartInfo = procStartInfo2;
        proc2.Start();
    }
```

Firstly, I've tried to just put everything from `cmd` to the process but it didn't work, after I tried to do what I actually have to: put all the string values as arguments but it didn't work either.

Instead  I am getting bunch of exceptions [image: first image]

[image: second img]

I'm  literally out of options as I've sat all day doing this. Does anyone have idea what problem it could be?

UPDATE:

I've managed to run `startInfo3` process. But `startInfo4` still doesn't work. I've checked both lines seem to produce the same so what's  wrong with it if they're are the same. Do I pass them incorrectly?

```
           ProcessStartInfo startInfo3 = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo3.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo3.Arguments = "/c" + @"C:\ant.bat -f=C:\build.xml -DinputFile=C:\Book1.xml -DstartDate=2018-06-20 -DxslFile=ProcessingDate -DoutputFile=fff";
            Process.Start(startInfo3);

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo4 = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo4.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo4.Arguments = "/c" + antFile + "-f=" + build + "-DinputFile=" + inputFile + "-DstartDate=" + startDate + "-DxslFile=" + startDate + "-DoutputFile=" + outputFile;
            Process.Start(startInfo4);
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, if a bit verbose. Perhaps your issue is with something in the environment? How are you running the C# program, how are you manually running `cmd`, can you try a simple console test program or get LINQPad and try that?

Comment: Doesn't look like you are putting any spaces in your command string (for proc2). That is what the command line parser uses to separate the arguments that are passed.

Comment: I've updated question, could you please take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a bit more I figured out an answer:

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo5 = new ProcessStartInfo();
            procStartInfo5.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            procStartInfo5.Arguments = $"/c{antFile} -f={build} -DinputFile={inputFile} -DstartDate={startDate} -DxslFile=ProcessingDate -DoutputFile={outputFile}";
            Process.Start(procStartInfo5);
```

Hope it helps someone!